# UnknownError finalizing mapreduce job

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mapreduce

I'm having a weird error on the completion of a mapreduce job that writes to the google storage, has anybody seen this before?

Final result for job '158354152558......' is 'success'

....

```
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~app/bqmapper.360899047207944804/libs/mapreduc/handlers.py", line 539, in _finalize_job
mapreduce_spec.mapper.output_writer_class().finalize_job(mapreduce_state)
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~app/bqmapper.360899047207944804/libs/mapreduce/output_writers.py", line 571, in finalize_job
files.finalize(create_filename)
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~app/bqmapper.360899047207944804/libs/mapreduce/lib/files/file.py", line 568, in finalize
f.close(finalize=True)
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~app/bqmapper.360899047207944804/libs/mapreduce/lib/files/file.py", line 291, in close
self._make_rpc_call_with_retry('Close', request, response)
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~app/bqmapper.360899047207944804/libs/mapreduce/lib/files/file.py", line 427, in _make_rpc_call_with_retry
_make_call(method, request, response)
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~app/bqmapper.360899047207944804/libs/mapreduce/lib/files/file.py", line 252, in _make_call
_raise_app_error(e)
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~app/bqmapper.360899047207944804/libs/mapreduce/lib/files/file.py", line 186, in _raise_app_error
raise UnknownError()
UnknownError
```

Answer (score 0):

After playing with it I found that an open file on the cloud storage has to be finalized in less than 1 hour or it will fail with this lovely UnknownError.

I mitigate the problem increasing the number of shards to make the mapping faster and changed the output_sharding strategy to "input" that creates one file per shard.